# Haskell TypeClasses - Override superclass function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider a type class like the following:

```
class A where
  fun1 :: String   -- undefined function     
  fun2 :: String   -- function with default def using fun1
  fun2 = fun1
```

I want to define different sub classes extending capabilities and also be able to provide different definitions for inherited `fun1`.
For example:

```
class A => B where
  fun3 :: String   -- other functions for B
  fun1 = "B"       -- provide def for super class fun1 

class A => C where
  fun4 :: String   -- other functions for C
  fun1 = "C"       -- provide def for super class fun1
```

When i instance B, i expect to inherit A capabilities (that is `fun2`) "customized" for B class. And similar for C.

But, compiler output:

> error: ‘fun1’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘B’

I'm aware that type classes are not 100% like ordinary OOP. But, isn't possible to "override" inherited functions in child classes?.

Comment: What if your type is both a member of `B` and `C`. A class in Haskell is more what is an interface in Java/C#.

Comment: It is also quite strange that your class has no type variable...

Comment: Your classes appear not to have a type parameter. I'm surprised those class heads compile.

Comment: @AntC I agree it's strange, but I expect that they compile (not that I've tried it). They'll just be pretty hard to use, at least without `TypeApplications`, because how else do you tell the compiler which instance you want to use when you refer to `fun1`?

Comment: "*I'm aware that type classes are not 100% like ordinary OOP.*". I think this is an understatement. Haskell's typeclasses are not much like classes in OO at all.

Comment: Yeah, it seems MultiParamTypeClasses extension allows no type parameter. I maded it simple, i thought it wasn't relevant for the question.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, no need for `TypeApplications`, but each of them admits only one instance! With `FunctionalDependencies`, you can even do `class C a | -> a` if you want, which is similar to `class C a; instance a ~ A => C a` (where `A` is the sole instance).

Comment: @fulem: it's very relevant. Using the same tyvar in `class A a => B a where ..` is the mechanism to say any instance of `B` must be an instance of `A`. @Robin without a tyvar, I don't see the `TypeApplications` will help: what do you apply the `@` to?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't get it. You've shown `class C a ...` so it _does_ have a type param. And `a ~ A => ...` means that `A` is a type, not a class.

Comment: @AntC, oh, I'm just pointing out that there are other weird edge cases with the right extensions. Both nullary classes and fundeps with empty left-hand sides are a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: @AntC: doh, good point.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for the explanation, this makes sense although still makes my head hurt a lot!

Comment: @leftroundabout: where is there any intro to Haskell that shows classes without type parameters? @fulem hacked the code to compile with `MultiParamTypeClasses` but where is there any docos for MPTCs that shows classes without type params? The code in the q just is not sensible Haskell. Whatever language or paradigm you're coming from, expecting to 'flip' code into some other language "does not show any research effort". That's why I downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware that type classes are not 100% like ordinary OOP

As Willem commented, that's an understatement. Haskell typeclasses are *completely and fundamentally* not like OO classes. Put simply, a typeclass is a set of types, whereas an OO class is a set of objects. In Haskell, we call “objects” *values*, and a set of values is roughly<sup>†</sup> what a *type* represents, not a class.

In other words, an OO class is more analogous to a single Haskell type than to a Haskell type class.

<sup>†</sup><sub>Again, a Haskell type is only *roughly* like a set of values. There are some important differences, notably Haskell doesn't support *subtypes* whereas an OO subclass does indeed represent a subset of the set of objects that the superclass represents.</sub>

If your example, reverse-engineered into C++, is

```
class A {
 public:
  virtual String fun1() =0;
  String fun2() { return fun1(); }
};

class B: public A {
 public:
  virtual String fun3() =0;
  String fun1() { return "B"; }
};

class B: public A {
 public:
  virtual String fun4() =0;
  String fun1() { return "B"; }
};
```

then the most direct translation to Haskell is:

```
data A = A { str1 :: String }

class SubsumesA a where
  fun2 :: a -> String

instance SubsumesA A where
  fun2 = str1

data B = B { superB :: A
           , str3 :: String }

instance SubsumesA B where
  fun2 = const "B"

data C = C { superC :: A
           , str2 :: String }

instance SubsumesA C where
  fun2 = const "C"
```

But this is generally not how you should go about writing Haskell type hierarchies. Haskell is not an OO language, don't treat it as if it were. Specifically, this style tends to run you into the [existential antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: Oh, nice C++. Indeed, that is more or less the OOP design i have in mind. I never used the advanced haskell features before (also, i don't work with haskell), but then i found some article online describing type classes as the most close thing to OOP with some examples. So, at first glance type classes look more like interfaces and not actual classes. But type classes also allow "default definitions", then i thought maybe is possible to represent hierarchies starting from some "abstract"-like (type) class. I messed it up, and obviously need more study.

Comment: Your transliteration to Haskell is very instructive. However, in the B and C instances, i think you mean `fun2 = str3` and `fun2 = str2`, respectively.  Then, `fun2 (B (A "A") "B") = "B"`, and similar for instance C.

Comment: In your example, `str1 . superB` works like "up-casting" to access super class functions. Good or bad analogy? hehe.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to define different sub classes extending capabilities and also be able to provide different definitions for inherited `fun1`.

(I'll leave aside for now why "inherited" isn't appropriate there.)

If you want 'to provide different definitions' for `fun1`, you need to provide something in the declaration of `fun1` that'll hook into the differences. **In other words**, you need a type parameter:

(Heh heh Note to the brains trust: this got into deep waters very fast, and needs advanced typaholic extensions. Doesn't work in GHC 7.10, for example.)

```
class A a  where
  fun1 :: a -> String
  fun2 :: String
  fun2 = fun1 (undefined :: a)
```

Note the derived type for `fun2 :: A a => String`. It still mentions parameter `a` even though `a` doesn't appear as an argument nor result. For `fun1 :: A a => a -> String`, `a` does appear as an argument, but of course there's no need for `fun1`'s instance decls to actually inspect its argument. And `fun2`'s default definition passes argument `undefined` to `fun1`, so it expects `fun1` won't inspect it. It's likely `a` is a 'phantom type' (many SO explanations of that term) parameter to the class. But we can't be sure until we see the instances.

(For advanced players: `fun2` also passes type param `a` via `ScopedTypeVariables` and the type annotation `:: a`, or could be via `TypeApplications`. Needs `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to accept that sig for `fun2`.)

Now we can overload `fun1, fun2` for different types

```
instance A Int where
  fun1 _ = "Int"                  -- ignores its arg, so that's a phantom
  -- fun2                         -- not overloaded, so takes default
```

Going back to your

> ```
>    class A => B where
>      fun3 :: String   -- other functions for B
>      fun1 = "B"       -- provide def for super class fun1
> ```

How do you expect to access this override for `fun1`? There's no mechanism, that's why the compiler complains. Instead you need to provide a hook back to some overloading of `fun1`. could be

```
newtype DB a = DB a
class A (DB a) => B a  where
  fun3 :: String                  -- again a is phantom
  fun3 = fun1 (undefined :: DB a)

instance B Int  where
  -- fun3 = fun1 (undefined :: DB Int)

instance A (DB Int)  where
  fun1 _ = "B"
```

Coming back to your "inherited `fun1`": the linkage from class `B` must be via some type to some `instance A` with an overload for `fun1`. I've used a `newtype` to keep the linkage lightweight. It's not an inheritance mechanism in the sense of OO.

Comment: Your first snippet is not working for me on GHC 8.6 (_The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
_). Tried `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, but not passing. Needs other extension?

Comment: " `fun2` also passes type param `a` via `ScopedTypeVariables` ". Also please get in the habit of reporting which line/which piece of code is getting reported, and the message in full. I guess you have `Could not deduce (A a0) arising from a use of 'fun1'` `In an equation for 'fun2': fun2 = fun1 (undefined :: a)`